# List All System's Fonts Tesseract OCR Text2Image

Tags: fonts, ocr, tesseract, text2image

i am using tesseract OCR on windows 10, i was able till now to create .box and .tif files for one font at a time, but when i try to make fontslist as described on the github website it doesn't work, giving me the warning

**WARNING: Could not find a font to render image title with!**

and it gives a fail for every font such as:

**Font Aldhabi failed with 62 hits = 21.60%**

also give **'%' (U+25) not covered by font** but i don't know what does that mean, anyways the command that I'm using is:
**text2image --text=training_text.txt --outputbase=eng.fontlist.txt --fonts_dir=C:\Windows\Fonts  --find_fonts --min_coverage=1.0 --render_per_font=false --fontconfig_tmpdir=C:\Tesseract\Tesseract-OCR**

Any idea how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance